# SQL job to clear LDF file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-job

I've created a SQL job to clear LDF file which runs once in a week.

Below is the screen shot for steps i've done.

[image: Steps added for sql job]

Also I've tried below queries

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('C:\MSSQLDATA\LOG\HDE.ldf', 1);

USE HDE;
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('C:\MSSQLDATA\LOG\HDE.ldf', 1);
GO
```

Any one help me that how can i run my job successfully by clearing the LDF log file.

Thanks
nag

Comment: You shouldn't be *clearing* your `.ldf` file..... it's there **for a very good reason!** You need to learn proper transaction log backup procedures...

Comment: Due to increase performance of machine we decide to do this once in a week. In future will include backup code also if needed.

Comment: Now that you have shrunk your LDF file..... it needs to grow again. Growing physical files take I/O and time.

Comment: Nick - Yeah that's why i created job and scheduled weekly once to clear/shrink the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer my self, below worked for me

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (HDE_log, 1);
```

By using above command it reduced from 16GB to 127MB, but is there any better solution to shirnk upto 1MB or 0MB?

Thanks